# how to update node.js 6.x to 8.x in windows operating sysytem using CLI

Tags: html, node.js, angular, nodes

i am unable to run angular 6 CLI on node.js 6.x its showing error that upgrade minimum node.js 8.xx to use angular CLI.

i tried with this code :

npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: How is npm-windows-upgrade supposed to help? It's Node. Not NPM. Use Node installer.

Comment: I found this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: Ok. Don't use it then, for the reasons listed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ensure that you can execute scripts on your system by running the following command from an elevated PowerShell. To run PowerShell as Administrator, click Start, search for PowerShell, right-click PowerShell and select Run as Administrator.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force

npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Want to just install the latest version? Sure:

```
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```

Comment: When it do the npm-windows-upgrade, it says " async ensureInternet () SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: I found there are version issues. Look at the bottom of this page. If you have an older version of Node, you need an older version of npm-windows-upgrade. https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade/blob/master/README.md#older-nodejs-versions

Answer (score 11):

Just download the latest version of nodejs and install it without uninstalling the previous version, the older version will be rewritten with the newer one. you wouldn't be having any compatibility issues.