# Upgrade to latest node version in windows through npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

I am trying to upgrade nodejs to latest version in my machine. I am getting below error after executing below commands through npm.

```
npm install -g n
```

This gave error as below

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@2.1.12: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":
"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243385/how-to-update-node-js-6-x-to-8-x-in-windows-operating-sysytem) question and executed below commands.

```
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```

I am getting below error in node command prompt

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-windows-upgrade\src\upgrader.j
s:26
  async ensureInternet () {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-win
dows-upgrade\bin\npm-windows-upgrade.js:8:16)
```

Could anyone please help on this?

Current version npm `6.9.0`
Current Version node `v6.10.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading Node.js to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) From the accepted answer "just reinstall node from the .msi in Windows from the node website. "

Comment: For windows, just download the installer from nodejs.org

Answer (score 1):

Just try downloading and installing the latest version from the [NodeJS website directly.](https://nodejs.org/en/)
Or use as package manager like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and download and update NodeJS via Powershell or your own script.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing to note is use powershell as administrator**

Please check node version,

For Node versions lower than v8.0, please use

```
 npm-windows-upgrade@5.0.0
```

For Node versions lower than v6.0, please use

```
 npm-windows-upgrade@4.1.1
```

For Node versions lower than v4.0, please use

```
 npm-windows-upgrade@3.1.1
```

My node version was 6.9.5. I tried

```
 npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade@5.0.0
```